# Different InvalidOperationException behavior between debug and runtime

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, invalidoperationexception

I have the following code in WinForm application with one button and one label:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => label1.Text = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
}
```

When I started program by VS debugger, the `label1.Text = ...` will throw a **System.InvalidOperationException** due to accessing control in working thread.  That is no problem.

But if I directly run the exe, I will see the working thread id be shown on label and no exception.

What cause this difference?

update:
If I start it in VS with release mode, there is no exception neither no thread id.  So that here is the third result.

Comment: Maybe you are running the older version of your exe file that doesn't contain this line of code?

Comment: @SalahAkbari Pretty sure the exe has the same code, or the thread id won't be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Simply: in release mode it isn't managing to detect your broken code as reliably. But: the code is still just as broken either way. You should **not** attempt to touch UI controls from worker threads, so: don't do that! Are you sure you didn't disable `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` somewhere? (note: you **should not** disable it; I'm just asking if perhaps you *have*)

Comment: This is my first time see ```Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls``` so I think it is not the reason... Btw, start in VS with release mode is another thing.  I understand the danger of accessing UI in working thread, I just found that and want to know why.